# Many to Many relationship Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor

I created a Blazor project and I have a many-to-many relationship between these classes:

```
public class ItemAttribute
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemAttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemAttributeCluster> itemAttributeClusters { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ItemAttributeCluster
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemAttributeClusterId { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public bool IsMultiChoice { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemAttribute> itemAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good, EF generates the Join table `ItemAttributeItemAttributeCluster`, ok.

Then I try to add a new cluster of `ItemAttributes` for the first time with my controller:

```
// Create
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ItemAttributeCluster itemAttributeCluster)
{
    _context.ItemAttributeClusters.Add(itemAttributeCluster);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok(itemAttributeCluster);
}
```

and I get this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ItemAttributes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What am I doing wrong? Why is EF trying to write something into 'ItemAttributes'? When i´m trying to create a new Cluster on 'ItemAttributesCluster' and the Join Table?

Migration Builder:
Join Table

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ItemAttributeItemAttributeCluster",
            columns: table => new
            {
                itemAttributeClustersItemAttributeClusterId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                itemAttributesItemAttributeId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ItemAttributeItemAttributeCluster", x => new { x.itemAttributeClustersItemAttributeClusterId, x.itemAttributesItemAttributeId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_ItemAttributeItemAttributeCluster_ItemAttributeClusters_itemAttributeClustersItemAttributeClusterId",
                    column: x => x.itemAttributeClustersItemAttributeClusterId,
                    principalTable: "ItemAttributeClusters",
                    principalColumn: "ItemAttributeClusterId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_ItemAttributeItemAttributeCluster_ItemAttributes_itemAttributesItemAttributeId",
                    column: x => x.itemAttributesItemAttributeId,
                    principalTable: "ItemAttributes",
                    principalColumn: "ItemAttributeId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

ItemAttributes

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ItemAttributes",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ItemAttributeId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)

            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ItemAttributes", x => x.ItemAttributeId);
            });
```

ItemAttributeCluster

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ItemAttributeClusters",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ItemAttributeClusterId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Titel = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                IsMultiChoice = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ItemAttributeClusters", x => x.ItemAttributeClusterId);
            });
```

Comment: I always advised not to count at EF , but create a many-to-many table, explicetly. As a matter of fact you will save much more time in the future then spent typing a couple more lines of code  creating table.

Comment: @Serge You may be right, but I have no idea how to do it manually, and I thought ef 5 would facing this functionality well

Comment: What is the content of `itemAttributeCluster`?

Comment: @GertArnold a itemAttributeCluster should content n-Attributes under a titel.

Comment: Yeah, but what *exactly* are you inserting there? It looks like the key values aren't 0.

Comment: @GertArnold the key value for a new itemAttributeCluster is '0'. I guess the new itemAttributeCluster isn't the problem , the problem is that as in the error mentioned ef try to write something into table 'ItemAttributes'.

Comment: Yes, as the error says, so what are the 'ItemAttributes' key values?

Answer (score 0):

If this was an existing schema for the ItemAttribute / Cluster tables and their PK were defined as identity columns, you will need to tell EF to expect them using the `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute alongside the Key designation.

When using a naming convention that EF recognizes like "ItemAttributeId" or "Id" I believe EF will default to assuming these are Identity columns, but with a name like "ItemAttributeCode" I believe it would assume a database generated option of "None" as default.

Comment: @T0bi You have to repeat db migration after this from the start

Comment: @Steve Py I changed it to "ItemAttributeId" and "ItemAttributeClusterId" and added a new migration and updated database, but same result

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about EF Core's convention behaviour, that may have changed. Did you add the [DatabaseGenerated(...)] attribute to the PKs in those entities? Were the entity classes written by you or generated? (Seems odd if these are generated and encountering Identity columns without marking the keys as Identity)

Comment: @StevePy I changed the [Key] to the [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] for Atributtes and Clusters but same Error. I written was i shown nothing more.

Comment: I suspect something strange is configured in your solution where either changes/migrations are not being applied against the database or otherwise running different code than your defined entities that you are updating. The error message you are seeing happens when inserting an entity that has an identity column that the entity isn't configured with so EF is attempting to insert the row with the PK/Identity set. If we've set the key to expect an Identity then that specific exception should simply not be happening.

Comment: @StevePy i updated the Migration Builder Code into the question may you can see some suspicious. But for me it seems allright.

Answer (score 0):

try to add some navigation properties

```
public ItemAttributeCluster()
        {
            AttributeClusters = new HashSet<AttributeCluster>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Titel { get; set; }
        public bool IsMultiChoice { get; set; }


        [InverseProperty(nameof(AttributeCluster.ItemAttributeClaster))]
        public virtual ICollection<AttributeCluster> AttributeClusters { get; set; }
    }


public partial class ItemAttribute
    {
        public ItemAttribute()
        {
            AttributeClusters = new HashSet<AttributeCluster>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(AttributeCluster.ItemAttribute))]
        public virtual ICollection<AttributeCluster> AttributeClusters { get; set; }
    }


public partial class AttributeCluster
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ItemAttributeId { get; set; }
        public int ItemAttributeClasterId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemAttributeId))]
        [InverseProperty("AttributeClusters")]
        public virtual ItemAttribute ItemAttribute { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemAttributeClasterId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(ItemAttributeCluster.AttributeClusters))]
        public virtual ItemAttributeCluster ItemAttributeClaster { get; set; 
    }
```

dbcontext (no any  fluent apis at all)

```
 public virtual DbSet<AttributeCluster> AttributeClusters { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<ItemAttribute> ItemAttributes { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<ItemAttributeCluster> ItemAttributeClusters { get; set; }
```

Test

```
var itemAttributeClaster = new ItemAttributeCluster { Titel="titleClaster2", IsMultiChoice=false};

var itemAttribute = new ItemAttribute{Title="attrTitle" };

var attributeClaster = new AttributeCluster { ItemAttribute = itemAttribute, ItemAttributeClaster = itemAttributeClaster };

_context.AttributeClusters.Add(attributeClaster);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

it created 1 record in each  of 3 tables

Comment: this generates the error: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'ItemAttribute.itemAttributeClusters' of type 'ICollection<ItemAttributeCluster>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: @T0bi Ok, I see I will need to add navigation. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I changed the Code to your answer, i migrated new and updated , still "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ItemAttributes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: @T0bi I tested this code, created db and run your post action. It created a record without any problem. Just clean everything, delete  migration folder, delete database and start from zero.

Comment: @T0bi See my updated answer about test.

Comment: I tried it a lot. Please, maybe i dont understand your solution correct. So step by step. I have in my Solution in my Models folder 3 Classes 'ItemAttribute','ItemAttribute' and 'AttributeCluster' or? Because it seems your solution is just one class with virtual classes in it? Should i do that instead of my construction?

Comment: @Yes, you should have 3 classes.  But pls  notice, they should not have  public ICollection<ItemAttribute> itemAttributes { get; set; } as you had. What is the error now.

Answer (score 0):

I give up on getting this to work with ef. I run several sql`s directly to achieve the same functionality and so far it works, not a satisfactory solution but it needs to be done.